# go fiber slice append changes all items

Tags: go, slice, go-fiber

seems like go slice append (string) changes all items when I render it to the template (also when I log the slice to the terminal)
I think this is a golang thing but I am not sure
[with Django template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqEuq.png)

Updated the code, but I still have the same problem
[with mutex and regular Html template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vViX.png)

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "sync"

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
    "github.com/gofiber/template/html"
)

func main() {
    engine := html.New("./views", ".html")
    app := fiber.New(fiber.Config{
        Views: engine,
    })

    type Whatever struct {
        Whatever string `json:"whatever" form:"whatever"`
    }
    var (
        itemsMu sync.RWMutex
        items   = []string{}
    )

    app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        itemsMu.RLock()
        defer itemsMu.RUnlock()
        return c.Render("index", fiber.Map{
            "Title": "Hello, World!",
            "Slice": items,
        })
    })

    app.Post("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
        w := new(Whatever)
        if err := c.BodyParser(w); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        itemsMu.Lock()
        items = append(items, w.Whatever)
        log.Println(items)
        itemsMu.Unlock()
        return c.Redirect("/")
    })
    log.Fatal(app.Listen(":3000"))
}
```

Comment: I'd suspect the problem is with your iteration. The append should be fine. Can you show your iteration code?

Comment: If you print `items` in the GET handler,  it is correct. So the problem must be somewhere in the template, which we can't look at.

Comment: `{% extends "./layouts/base.html" %}
<title>{% block title %}Index{% endblock title %}</title>
{% block content %}
<div>{{ Title }}</div>
<ul>
    {% for s in slice %}
    <li>{{ s }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
<form action="/" method="POST">
    <input type="search" name="whatever" id="whatever">
    <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
{% endblock %}`

Answer (score 0):

HTTP requests are served on different goroutines. Variables scoped outside of requests (such as your `items`) that are accessed from requests must be synchronized.

Accessing (writing) writing variables from different goroutines is a data race and undefined behaviour.

Add proper synchronization, then see the result.

For example:

```
var (
    itemsMu sync.RWMutex
    items = []string{}
) 

app.Get("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    itemsMu.RLock()
    defer itemsMu.RUnlock()
    return c.Render("index", fiber.Map{
        "Title": "Hello, World!",
        "slice": items,
    })
})

app.Post("/", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    w := new(Whatever)
    if err := c.BodyParser(w); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    itemsMu.Lock()
    items = append(items, w.Whatever)
    itemsMu.Unlock()
    return c.Redirect("/")
})
```

Comment: I think that this is it, but I still get the error

Comment: Please update the question with the synchronized code and error messages you get.

Comment: a funny thing, with Postman it works fine (with and without RWMutex), looks like a session bug

Answer (score 0):

I know, I'm a little late to the party, but I ran into a similar problem (golang noob here) and I suggest if someone's running into a similar problem that they look at GoFiber's [Zero Allocation](https://docs.gofiber.io/#zero-allocation)

Something along these lines should work (straight from the docs):

```
app.Get("/:foo", func(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    // Variable is now immutable
    result := utils.CopyString(c.Params("foo")) 

    // ...
})
```